# Unsatisfied dependency expressed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some class as below

```
public abstract interface IGenRepository  <T> {

 public abstract List<T> getAll(String filter);
}
```

and

```
@Repository
public abstract class GenRepository<T> implements IGenRepository<T> {
protected abstract Class<T> myFunction();
 @Override
public List<T> getAll(String filter) {

.......}}
```

all those Class is general and now I want to use those Class in my project

```
public  interface IProductRepository extends IGenRepository<Product> {}
```

and implatation this Class is:

```
@Repository
public class ProductRepository extends GenRepository<Product> {}
```

When in use this Class as:

`@Autowired
    private IProductRepository iProductRepository;`

Have this Error

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'productService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'iProductRepository'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.tax.repositories.IProductRepository' available:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
 {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not implementing `IProductRepository`  `ProductRepository`  class . 
Change the code as below-

```
@Repository
public class ProductRepository implements IProductRepository extends GenRepository<Product> {}
```